# get querystring variables to display on static page

Tags: magento2.3, variables, querystring

How to get querystring information and display on a landingpage?

This is a link created on another website with variables to pass to magento2.3.1 website.
www.mymagentowebsite.com/staticpage.html?w=150&h=220&c=2&shape=LZ0005

now I want to get the variables w,h,c and shape
and display them on a static page.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams()
```

or you shoud pass varable name in that like

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams('w')
```